# Scraping using OpenRefine / GoogleRefine omits <div class="itemfooter"> tags

Tags: html, web-scraping, openrefine

I wanted to scrape a simple set of pages and thought I'd use OpenRefine to grab the HTML for each one, and then parse it. I'm after the contents of a particular tag, but strangely enough, OpenRefine isn't showing that particular tag. That's the first time OR has omitted tags, and I'm not sure why. Here are the specifics:

I'm scraping the categories assigned to each blog post on the following blog:

http://stripsjournal.canalblog.com/tag/Les%20Unes%20de%20Charlie%20Hebdo/p00-0.html

The page URLs range from p00-0.html to p330-0.html.

So I've got a column of pages, from 0 to 330, which I combine with the URL thus:

"http://stripsjournal.canalblog.com/tag/Les%20Unes%20de%20Charlie%20Hebdo/p" + value + "-0.html"

When I scrape the HTML contents of each of each page, I expect to see something along the lines of the following (here's the expected result from the first entry):

```
<h3>Les prédictions du mage Houellebecq - Charlie Hebdo N°1177 - 7 janvier 2015</h3>

<div class="itemfooter"> Thèmes >> <a href="http://stripsjournal.canalblog.com/tag/2022"         
rel="tag">2022</a>, 

    <a href="http://stripsjournal.canalblog.com/tag/Houellebecq" rel="tag">Houellebecq</a>, 

    <a href="http://stripsjournal.canalblog.com/tag/Les%20Unes%20de%20Charlie%20Hebdo" rel="tag">Les         
    Unes de Charlie Hebdo</a>, 

    <a href="http://stripsjournal.canalblog.com/tag/livres" rel="tag">livres</a>, 

    <a href="http://stripsjournal.canalblog.com/tag/ramadan" rel="tag">ramadan</a>, 

    <a href="http://stripsjournal.canalblog.com/tag/religion" rel="tag">religion</a>, 

    <a href="http://stripsjournal.canalblog.com/tag/%C3%A9lections" rel="tag">élections</a>

</div>

<p><p style="text-align: center;"><a name="IMG_101392446"     
href="http://p2.storage.canalblog.com/24/72/177230/101392446_o.jpg" target="_blank"><img     
src="http://p2.storage.canalblog.com/24/72/177230/101392446.jpg" border="0" alt="01-1177-
Houellebecq" width="355" /></a></p>
```

Instead, OR omits the  tag completely and yields the following output:

```
<h3>Les prédictions du mage Houellebecq - Charlie Hebdo N°1177 - 7 janvier 2015</h3>

<p><p style="text-align: center;"><a name="IMG_101392446"     
href="http://p2.storage.canalblog.com/24/72/177230/101392446_o.jpg" target="_blank"><img     
src="http://p2.storage.canalblog.com/24/72/177230/101392446.jpg" border="0" alt="01-1177-
Houellebecq" width="355" /></a></p>
```

Did I make some ridiculous absent-minded mistake, or is something up with OR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenRefine isn't omitting anything, the web site is sending different HTML depending on what it thinks the client is.  If you look at the HTML that you've received, if it's the same as what I got, you'll find that it's for the mobile version of the site, not the desktop version.

It's unclear what they're using as a signal to trigger the sending of the mobile version (and OpenRefine doesn't provide very good control of HTML header fields), so you may not be able to work around it easily, but OpenRefine is not dropping anything that it receives.

Answer (score 1):

This is where a proper User Agent string or Browser ID might come in handy.  Faking a real browser that is sending the request, rather than our default User Agent string of "OpenRefine/2.6".

If using the development version or what to hack it a bit:
If you want to tweak or set the User Agent aka Browser ID, then you can do so at the bottom of this: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/blob/master/main/src/com/google/refine/RefineServlet.java

and then build.

If using the standard version:
For simplicity you can navigate to `http://localhost:3333/preferences` and set a property named "User-Agent" to equal a value you wish, such as "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"